# 90s Anime where a samurai’s village is attacked by purple demon dogs

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm looking for the name of a show set in an age before modern technology that featured a samurai in blue whose village was attacked by purple demon dogs, his arm was infected and he left the village seeking a cure.

Some details will be wrong as I saw this from a blockbuster video my mom rented for me when I was 13 thinking it was a cartoon.

Answer (score 6):

This is *[Princes Mononoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Mononoke)*

> In Muromachi Japan, an Emishi village is attacked by a demon. The last Emishi prince, Ashitaka, kills it before it reaches the village, but its corruption curses his right arm. The curse gives him superhuman strength, but will eventually spread through his body and kill him. The villagers discover that the demon was a boar god, Nago, corrupted by an iron ball lodged in his body. The village's wise woman tells Ashitaka that he may find a cure in the western lands Nago came from, but he cannot return to his homeland. Before Ashitaka leaves, his younger sister Kaya gives him her crystal dagger so that he would not forget her.

### Trailer

One non-matching part is that Nago, the corrupted boar god who attacks Ashitaka's village, is not a "purple demon dog", but the rest seems to match up nicely.

Comment: If this is the correct answer for you, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I will take a look at this one. Seems like the best bet. But just out of curiosity is there any others that might be similar?